# how to authorize azure container registry in java to get list of repos and images under that

Tags: java, azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry, azure-authentication

I have Azure container registry, My use case is through java code

I want to get all the repos of azure container registry instance.
From each repo I need the list of all container images
Want to push the container images and pull the container images from the repo.

Can you please help ne what java SDK, I need to use.
How can i authenticate through java code to connect azure container registry.
Also i have service principle account - how can I use this in java

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: The problem is not solved yet. How can i acheive authentication for azure container registry. Need help in authnetication token

Comment: As I said in the answer, you have a service principal then you just need to assign a Contributor role to it so that you can use the client id as the user and secret as the password for the basic authentication method. Of course, you can use the admin user and password of the ACR.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it help you, please accept it.

Comment: Do you still work on this question? I didn't get any response and you also do not accept it.

Comment: its working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Azure does not provide the SDK to get a list of repos and images. But actually, the Azure Container Registry is a private docker registry. So you can use the Docker API to get the things you need. For example, you want to get a list of the repos in ACR, then you can use the API like below:

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: basic $credential" https://myacr.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog
```

The example result:

[image]

When you use a service principal as the credential of the ACR, you need to assign the service principal a role with enough permissions. You can get more details about the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/).